# How to add content-Type headers in tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

I'm serving .js files from inside a war in tomcat8.  Its adding only these two headers.

```
Date:   Mon, 12 Feb 2018 16:14:13 GMT
ETag:   W/"3087-1518446418000"
```

(verified in two browsers)

`tomcat/conf/web.xml` specifies

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

To be sure I added in my war's `web.xml` too.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Tomcat 8, all pretty standard, its a while since I tried serving static content from tomcat but I have a reason to do that.

web.xmlheader is currenlty (tried other ones)

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here.  My problem was not generic to all JavaScript.

I had a servlet mapped to

```
<url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
```

And a JavaScript file called

```
/js/foo.js
```

Tomcat was able to correctly resolve the servlet and the JS file but something broke the headers in the process, I'm going to raise a bug report with Tomcat.